# Connection failed - ETL Data From Redshift to RDS using AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am trying to ETL data from Redshift to RDS. Here is my script

```
# Write data to RDS
RDS_node = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf(
   frame=AmazonRedshift_node1,
   catalog_connection="aurora-destination-connection",
   connection_options={
     "dbtable": "vendor",
     "database": "etl_redshift_test"
   },
   transformation_ctx="RDS_node",
)
```

Every time I get a connection attempt failed. I tried multiple script versions

Version 1:

```
# Stage 2: Write data to Aurora PostgreSQL RDS
redshift_df.write \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", rds_url) \
    .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver") \
    .option("dbtable", rds_table) \
    .mode("append") \
    .option("user", user) \
    .option("password", password) \
    .save()
```

Version 2:

```
# Convert the DynamicFrame to a DataFrame for debugging purposes
 redshift_df = AmazonRedshift_node1.toDF()

 redshift_df.write.jdbc(
    url=jdbc_url,
    table="vendor",
    mode="overwrite",
    properties=connection_properties
 )
```

Comment: Can you manually test the connection and share the error message?